# ANTLR4 non-greedy rules with stop token

Tags: antlr4

In  the lexer I have :

```
AT:                         '@'                         -> mode(OPERATOR);
DOUBLE_AT:                  '@@'                        ;
CURLY_CLOSE:                '}'                         { block_nesting > 0 && block_nesting >= curly_nesting }? { curly_nesting--; block_nesting--; };
NORMAL_ELSE:                'else'                      { previous_is_parenthesis_close() }? { block_nesting++; tokens.clear(); setType(ELSE); } -> mode(RYTHM);
NWS:                        [\t\r\n ]+                  { setType(WS); };
CONTENT:                    .+? ('@' | '}' | 'else' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' ) ;
```

The CONTENT rule matches all, but including the tokens that terminate it. Which is not what the grammar needs : It needs to match all, until the terminator, not including.

Is there a way to do what I want ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following code:

```
CONTENT:   ~('@' | '}' | 'e' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' )+;
NOT_ELSE:   'e' -> type(CONTENT);
```

But in this case, you will have several `CONTENT` rules instead of one. You can resolve this problem on the parser rules level.

Comment: That just moves the problem. It also makes the parser need to process a lot more data then when CONTENT is just a bunch of combined characters.

I'm not in the process of using a TokenStreamRewriter, but that is barely documented. And does not work as I expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've created a method that merges centain tokens into one, and used reflection to feed that new list to the parser. Not exactly pretty, but it works for now.